# Request get blocked when over 10240 content-length

Tags: azure

fter trying a lot of combinations this is the error i get, when Json request is less than 10240 it goes through without problem. I am using angular deployed on an azure server. My backend is written in nodeJS. I did not had this issues yesterday, just today.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at URL from origin URL has been blocked by
> CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource. polyfills-es2015.289…68f30b383baa32.js:1 POST URL
> net::ERR_FAILED main-es2015.c96fe56….js:1 ERROR C {headers: h, status:
> 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: URL , ok: false, …} error:
> ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0,
> total: 0, type: "error", …} headers: h {normalizedNames: Map(0),
> lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)} message: "Http failure response for
> URL : 0 Unknown Error" name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 0
> statusText: "Unknown Error" url: "URL "

Comment: Please check this topic [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167656/nodejs-max-header-size-in-http-request/51259375)

Comment: This error doesn't seem to be related to the length of the request body. You should read the error message and resolve the actual problem that it indicates first.